# How to call parents function from child in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I call a parents function in the Child class with the current context (this) of the Child?

I tried to use `Parent.testFunc.call(this);` but I get an error (Cannot read property 'call' of undefined).

```
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

var Parent = function(){
    this.test = function(){
        alert("worked");
    };
};

var Child = function(){
    Parent.call(this);

    //THIS GIVES THE ERROR **
    Parent.test.call(this);
};

extend(Child, Parent);

var child = new Child();
```

How can I call the parent function called test from the Child keeping the same context (this) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, you'd just use

```
this.test();
```

...because the function is attached directly to the instance itself by the `Parent` function.

Example:

```js
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

var Parent = function(){
    this.test = function(){
        console.log("worked");
    };
};

var Child = function(){
    Parent.call(this);

    this.test(this);
};

extend(Child, Parent);

var child = new Child();
```

In general, it doesn't matter at what level the function was created, you can access it on `this`. The only hassle is when you have a function that's redefined. For instance, where `Parent` has `test` and then you also want `Child` to have its own version of `test` *but* want `Child` instances to also be able to call `Parent`'s `test` (perhaps from `Child`'s).

That's difficult to arrange when you create functions in the constructor as you're doing, but easier (though still verbose and awkward) when you put them on the prototype.

Just for completeness:

```js
function extend(Child, Parent) {
    Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    Child.prototype.constructor = Child;
}

var Parent = function(x){
    this.x = x;
};
Parent.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log("Parent's test, x = " + this.x);
};

var Child = function(x){
    Parent.call(this, x);

    this.test(this);
};
extend(Child, Parent);
Child.prototype.test = function() {
    Parent.prototype.test.call(this);
    console.log("Child's test, x = " + this.x);
};

var child = new Child(42);
```

And finally, that example is much simpler with ES2015+ `class` syntax:

```js
class Parent {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    test() {
        console.log("Parent's test, x = " + this.x);
    }
};

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(x) {
        super(x);
        this.test();
    }
    test() {
        super.test();
        console.log("Child's test, x = " + this.x);
    };
};

const child = new Child(42);
```

...which you can use now on cutting-edge browsers, and others with transpiling (perhaps with [Babel](http://babeljs.io)).